# How would I solve the following trig equation?

Tags: trigonometry

It is

$3\sin x+4\cos x=2 $

What I did is

$(3\sin x)^2=((2-4\cos x)^2$ to get

$9-9\cos^2x=4-16\cos x+16\cos^2 x$ then I got

$25\cos^2 x-16\cos x-5=0$

However I am having trouble finding the root I tried using the quadratic formula and got x=.866 I am not sure what  I do wrong.

Comment: $\color{maroon}{\cos}( x)=.866$ (approximately; which is a bit off)... The variable in your quadratic is $\cos x$, not $x$.

Comment: You are correct  x is closer to .869909

Comment: But I cannot seem to get the right answer.

Comment: $x$ has two values $0.86990908339, -0.22990908339$

Comment: yes because it plus and minus in the quadratic formula.

Comment: What you get is $$\cos x=\frac{8\pm3\sqrt{21}}{25}$$ So $$x=\arccos\left(\frac{8\pm3\sqrt{21}}{25}\right)$$

Comment: Alternately, divide through by $5=\sqrt{3^2+4^2}$, and let $\phi$ be the angle whose cosine is $\frac{3}{5}$ and whose sine is $\frac{4}{5}$.

Comment: I did arccos(.87) and I got .5155 but on the answer key of my book it says the correct answer is 1.80,5.76

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: Did you check whether the answer is correct?

Comment: Taking the inverse cosine will give you the value of $x$ in the interval $[0,\pi]$ that satisfies the quadratic equation. In this case, you obtain $x\approx .516\,\text{rad}$. But $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$, so another solution to the quadratic is $x\approx -.516\approx 5.76\,\text{rad}$.  Now, you squared both sides of your original equation, so you need to check if these answers satisfy the original equation (before you squared both sides). The former works, the latter doesn't (then $2-4\cos(x)$ is negative).  And, don't forget about the other root of the quadratic.

Comment: Oh I see now the other solution works. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fact I could find through my old texts that:

If $a,b$ be real numbers which $a^2+b^2\neq 0$ then $$\exists\alpha\in\mathbb R, \;\; a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(x+\alpha)$$ I added this, maybe be helpful as a hint.

Comment: I miss you Babak! +1 ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Me too Amy................

Answer (score 2):

This works out nicely almost-automatically with groebner basis. Your single equation is equivalent to the two equations

$$s^2+c^2=1$$
$$3s+4c=2$$

The groebner basis in lexicographical order is

$$4c+3s-2 ~~\textrm{and}~~ 25s^2-12s-12$$

So solving the quadratic equation $25s^2-12s-12=0$ gives us the solutions! $$s_{1,2}=\frac{6}{25}\frac{+}{-}\frac{4}{25}\sqrt{21}$$ and $c_{1,2}=(2-3s_{1,2})/4$. Then $x_{1,2}=\arcsin(s_{1,2})=\arccos(c_{1,2})$. However, if you have some software to do groebner basis for you, then it probably already has a solve method to use directly on your first equation.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

$$a\sin x+b\cos x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(x+\varphi),$$
where the phase shift $\varphi=\arcsin\left({b\over \sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$ when $a>0$.

So, in your situation, you get $$5\sin(x+\varphi)=2\implies x+\varphi=\arcsin(2/5) \implies x=\arcsin(2/5)-\arcsin(4/5)\approx-0.51.$$

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm not sure if you want *a* solution or *all* solutions, but this does the bulk of the work.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are just looking for solutions in the interval $[0,2\pi]$. And then what you have done is pretty much correct. So you start with

$$3\sin x+4\cos x=2.$$

And this implies $25\cos^2 x-16\cos x-5=0$.

Let $t = cos(x)$. Then the equation just says $25t^2 - 16t - 5 = 0$. The two solutions are
$$\begin{align}
t &= \frac{16 \pm\sqrt{16^2 + 500}}{50} \\ 
&= \frac{16 \pm \sqrt{756}}{50} \\
&= \frac{16 \pm 6\sqrt{21}}{50} \\
&= \frac{8\pm 3\sqrt{21}}{25}\\
&= \begin{cases}0.86990908 \\ -0.229900908\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
That is you want to find the solutions to
$$
\cos(x) = \begin{cases}0.86990908 \\ -0.229900908\end{cases}
$$
By taking $\cos^{-1}$ you can get possible solutions, but when you do that you have to remember that $2\pi$ minus each possible solution is also a solution (to the cosine equation. So you get:
$$
x = \begin{cases}  0.51558\quad\text{or}\quad 5.76741 \\ 1.80278\quad\text{or}\quad 4.84952 \end{cases}.
$$
In getting your quadratic, you squared both sides, so you have to be careful. We should always go back and check that we got valid solutions. When you do that you realize that only
$$
x= 1.80278\quad\text{and}\quad x= 5.76741
$$
are valid solutions.

(All this was of course essentially contained in the comments to the question)